# Find repeated values in a column and filter them by another column values

Tags: google-sheets

i have two columns, A contains various values, B contains also various values but from a list (Dropdown Data validation).

i want a formula in D, E, that brings only repeated values in A where B contains 3 specific values, and this result also (i mean D,E) should be unique.

So i'm looking for some formula like this :

`D = UNIQUE(  Query( A1:B;  "Slecet A, B where COUNT(A)>1 AND B = Value1 OR B = Value2 OR B = Value3 "; 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```cpp
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,1<COUNTIF(A:A,A:A),REGEXMATCH(""&B:B,"(?i)\b(Value1|Value2|Value3)\b")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in columns A and B, and you want to filter values based on the conditions you mentioned, you can use the following formulas:

In cell D1:

> `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A, (COUNTIF(A:A, A:A) > 1) * ((B:B = "Value1") + (B:B = "Value2") + (B:B = "Value3"))))`

This formula filters column A based on the conditions you provided and returns only unique values.

In cell E1:

> `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D:D, QUERY(A:B, "select A, B where B = 'Value1' or B = 'Value2' or B = 'Value3'", 0), 2, FALSE)))`

This formula looks up the corresponding values from column B for the unique values in column D, based on the specified conditions in column B.

Remember to adjust the ranges A:A and B:B to match the actual range of your data, and replace "Value1", "Value2", and "Value3" with the specific values you want to filter by. Also, ensure that the formula is entered only in one row, and it will automatically populate the entire column due to the use of array formulas.